# I can not view the mesh by applying a complex shaders

Tags: javascript, webgl, babylonjs

I'm new in computer graphics.
I'm building a local web application to highlight the effects of shaders on meshes.
I have problems with the application of the bumbp mapping shader which causes my mesh to disappear from the scene.At the moment, i can make only simple shaders work inside my application. 
I would like to see my mesh with a Bumbp effect.
this is what I did:

Vertex shader code:

```
<script type="application/vertexShader"  id="vertexBumbpShaderCode">

        precision highp float;

        attribute vec3 vert_pos;
        attribute vec3 vert_tang;
        attribute vec3 vert_bitang;
        attribute vec2 vert_uv;

        uniform mat4 model_mtx;
        uniform mat4 norm_mtx;
        uniform mat4 proj_mtx;

        varying vec2 frag_uv;
        varying vec3 ts_light_pos; // Tangent space values
        varying vec3 ts_view_pos;  //
        varying vec3 ts_frag_pos;  //

        mat3 transposes(in mat3 inMatrix)
        {
        vec3 i0 = inMatrix[0];
        vec3 i1 = inMatrix[1];
        vec3 i2 = inMatrix[2];

        mat3 outMatrix = mat3(
            vec3(i0.x, i1.x, i2.x),
            vec3(i0.y, i1.y, i2.y),
            vec3(i0.z, i1.z, i2.z)
        );

        return outMatrix;
        }

    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = proj_mtx * vec4(vert_pos, 1.0);
        ts_frag_pos = vec3(model_mtx * vec4(vert_pos, 1.0));
        vec3 vert_norm = cross(vert_bitang, vert_tang);

        vec3 t = normalize(mat3(norm_mtx) * vert_tang);
        vec3 b = normalize(mat3(norm_mtx) * vert_bitang);
        vec3 n = normalize(mat3(norm_mtx) * vert_norm);
        mat3 tbn = transposes(mat3(t, b, n));

        vec3 light_pos = vec3(1, 2, 0);
        ts_light_pos = tbn * light_pos;
        // Our camera is always at the origin
        ts_view_pos = tbn * vec3(0, 0, 0);
        ts_frag_pos = tbn * ts_frag_pos;

        frag_uv = vert_uv;
    } 

        </script>
```

Fragment shader code:

```
<script type="application/fragmentShader"  id="fragmentBumbpShaderCode" >
            precision highp float;

            uniform sampler2D tex_norm;
            uniform sampler2D tex_diffuse;
            uniform sampler2D tex_depth;
            /*
                The type is controlled by the radio buttons below the canvas.
                0 = No bump mapping
                1 = Normal mapping
                2 = Parallax mapping
                3 = Steep parallax mapping
                4 = Parallax occlusion mapping
            */
            uniform int type;
            uniform int show_tex;
            uniform float depth_scale;
            uniform float num_layers;

            varying vec2 frag_uv;
            varying vec3 ts_light_pos;
            varying vec3 ts_view_pos;
            varying vec3 ts_frag_pos;

            vec2 parallax_uv(vec2 uv, vec3 view_dir)
            {
                if (type == 2) {
                    // Parallax mapping
                    float depth = texture2D(tex_depth, uv).r;    
                    vec2 p = view_dir.xy * (depth * depth_scale) / view_dir.z;
                    return uv - p;  
                } else {
                    float layer_depth = 1.0 / num_layers;
                    float cur_layer_depth = 0.0;
                    vec2 delta_uv = view_dir.xy * depth_scale / (view_dir.z * num_layers);
                    vec2 cur_uv = uv;

                    float depth_from_tex = texture2D(tex_depth, cur_uv).r;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                        cur_layer_depth += layer_depth;
                        cur_uv -= delta_uv;
                        depth_from_tex = texture2D(tex_depth, cur_uv).r;
                        if (depth_from_tex < cur_layer_depth) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (type == 3) {
                        // Steep parallax mapping
                        return cur_uv;
                    } else {
                        // Parallax occlusion mapping
                        vec2 prev_uv = cur_uv + delta_uv;
                        float next = depth_from_tex - cur_layer_depth;
                        float prev = texture2D(tex_depth, prev_uv).r - cur_layer_depth
                                     + layer_depth;
                        float weight = next / (next - prev);
                        return mix(cur_uv, prev_uv, weight);
                    }
                }
            }

            void main(void)
            {
                vec3 light_dir = normalize(ts_light_pos - ts_frag_pos);
                vec3 view_dir = normalize(ts_view_pos - ts_frag_pos);

                // Only perturb the texture coordinates if a parallax technique is selected
                vec2 uv = (type < 2) ? frag_uv : parallax_uv(frag_uv, view_dir);

                vec3 albedo = texture2D(tex_diffuse, uv).rgb;
                if (show_tex == 0) { albedo = vec3(1,1,1); }
                vec3 ambient = 0.3 * albedo;

                if (type == 0) {
                    // No bump mapping
                    vec3 norm = vec3(0,0,1);
                    float diffuse = max(dot(light_dir, norm), 0.0);
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse * albedo + ambient, 1.0);

                } else {
                    // Normal mapping
                    vec3 norm = normalize(texture2D(tex_norm, uv).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);
                    float diffuse = max(dot(light_dir, norm), 0.0);
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse * albedo + ambient, 1.0);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Javascript Code using Babylonjs:

```
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startGame, false);


    function startGame(){

        var rubikBox; 
        var sphere;
        var currentMesh;

        if (BABYLON.Engine.isSupported()) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
            var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, false);
            var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
            var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 0, Math.PI / 2, 10, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);

          //  camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(60, 50, 100));
            camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
            camera.lowerBetaLimit = 0.1;
            camera.upperBetaLimit = (Math.PI / 2) * 0.99;
            camera.lowerRadiusLimit = 100;


            // Creating light
            var light = new BABYLON.PointLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
            light.diffuse = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
            light.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0);

            //rubikBox = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("red", 20, scene);
            sphere = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("Sphere", 100, 40, scene);
            currentMesh = 'earth';
            // Creating sphere
            sphere.position.z = 1;

             var amigaMaterial = new BABYLON.ShaderMaterial("amiga", scene, {
                vertexElement: "vertexShaderCode",
                fragmentElement: "fragmentShaderCode",
            },
            {
                attributes: ["position", "uv"],
                uniforms: ["worldViewProjection"]
            });

            amigaMaterial.setTexture("textureSampler", new BABYLON.Texture("earthmap1k.jpg", scene));
            amigaMaterial.setFloat("time", 0);
            amigaMaterial.setVector3("cameraPosition", BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
            amigaMaterial.backFaceCulling = false;

            sphere.material = amigaMaterial;

            engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.005;
                scene.render();
            });
            document.getElementById("Bumbp").addEventListener("click", BumbpShader, false);

        function BumbpShader() {


                  var BumbpMaterial = new BABYLON.ShaderMaterial("amiga", scene, {
                        vertexElement: "vertexBumbpShaderCode",
                        fragmentElement: "fragmentBumbpShaderCode",
                    },
                    {
                        attributes: ["position", "uv"],
                        uniforms: ["worldViewProjection"]
                    });

                    switch(currentMesh){

                    case "cube": 
                        BumbpMaterial.setTexture("textureSampler", new BABYLON.Texture("cubik.jpg", scene));
                        BumbpMaterial.setFloat("time", 0);
                        BumbpMaterial.setVector3("cameraPosition", BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
                        BumbpMaterial.backFaceCulling = false;
                        rubikBox.material = BumbpMaterial;

                        break;
                    case "earth":
                        BumbpMaterial.setTexture("textureSampler", new BABYLON.Texture("earthmap1k.jpg", scene));
                        BumbpMaterial.setFloat("time", 0);
                        BumbpMaterial.setVector3("cameraPosition", BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
                        BumbpMaterial.backFaceCulling = false;
                        sphere.material = BumbpMaterial;
                        break;

                     }



                scene.render();
                return;
            }   
}
```

I have minimized the affected lines, I add, saying that the chrome console does not give me any kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you are missing to declare all your uniforms in the ShaderMaterial constructor

Comment: Thank you David!you are right. it was a Classic error to copy and paste, anyway I really appreciate your work with babylon js, I'm using it for my university thesis. If you were available I would like to ask you for some other advice.

Comment: Please do, no problem :)

Comment: This is what i need: to import a new mesh into my scene.
This is what id did :
-download a .obj
-imported in blender 
-exported in .babylon in my directory 
in this directory i have a skull.babylon and a skull.log generated from blender. following:https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#JUKXQD#0 
But i receive an error from the browser, when i'm trying to import the skull:
 skull.babylon.manifest?1522092057312 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
AND skull.babylon.manifest Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 

i don't know why, Thanks in advance David.